# Starting a GridGain Node

Tags: java, gridgain

When I start GridGain node, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/gridgain/grid/loaders/cmdline/GridCommandLineLoader
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably GRIDGAIN_HOME environment variable is not set or is set incorrectly. Please, set GRIDGAIN_HOME to your GridGain installation folder.

Answer (score 2):

Dmitriy is correct GRIDGAIN_HOME environment variable is not set or is set incorrectly. this is how you can set it.

**Windows**

SET  GRIDGAIN_HOME=your_installation_home

**Linux and UNIX:**

export  GRIDGAIN_HOME=your_installation_home

source http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GFAQ/Troubleshooting+FAQ#